# How to get Unicode characters from ISO-8859-6 data?

Tags: c#, unicode, decode

I have some data encoded in ISO-8859-6, which I am reading from a bar-code scanner using a serial port. How do I map this ISO-8859-6 data into Unicode characters?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.getencoding.aspx) to get a [`System.Text.Encoding`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx) object for ISO-8859-6, either

```
System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-6")
```

Or

```
System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(28596)
```

And then you can pass your encoded ISO-8859-6 bytes to the object's `GetString()` or `GetChars()` method.